# ¿Como hacer que mi página asp.net no necesite un ping antes de trabajar?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, iis, timeout

Buenas Tardes,

Mi problema es el siguiente: tengo un web-server que además tiene una página web, el web server funciona bien, el problema es que, para acceder a la página, necesito hacer una primera solicitud a la página a través del navegador, solicitud que quedará timeout antes porsupuesto, de hecho ese es el problema, pero la siguiente solicitud a esa de hecho funcionará.

El problema parece ser que los ASP se cierran después de un rato de inactividad, eso significa que si nadie ve la página por un tiempo, al parecer el servidor la cierra y solo la vuelve a abrir cuando alguien lo solicita, lo que es en sí complejo, porque no espero grandes flujos de personas llendo hacia mi página y necesito que se mantenga responsiva todo el tiempo, es válido mencionar que los servicios de tipo ASO funcionan todo el tiempo de manera ininterrumpida, y también estan publicados en el mismo IIS.

He leído por ahí que podría hacer una aplicación consola que haga ping a la página cada cierta cantidad de tiempo para evitar que se baje y mantenerla activa siempre, pero preferiría evitar esa forma de responder al problema que me parece, por lo bajo, inadecuada.

**¿Existirá otra solución al problema que no requiera una aplicación adicional?**

Cualquier comentario constructivo que ayude a mejorar esta pregunta, también será muy bienvenido.

Desde ya, muchisimas gracias.

Comment: No añades mucha información sobre tu problema, pero parece que quieres tratar los síntomas en lugar de la enfermedad: ¿Por qué el servidor no responde a la primera petición? ¿Entra en modo ahorro de energía?

Comment: Listo, agregué mas información.

Comment: Es un poco extraño. Que hace tu aplicación? Es posible que la operación tarde demasiado la primera vez, estas haciendo alguna consulta a alguna base de datos que pueda estar provocando el problema?

Comment: No, lo sé porque la aplicación ya esta lista y funciona de maravilla, de hecho le instalé un auto-reloader a mi browser para que el browser haga un llamado cada 10 segundos, de modo que no se "apague" la página cuando hago pruebas y funciona de maravilla.

Literalmente el browser solo hace un "ping", se conecta y listo, nada de bases de datos en el caso del uso que da el browser, y tras ese uso, desde el segundo uso en adelante, las aplicaciones que consumen la página pueden hacerlo sin problema, aparte la página no tiene llamadas previas, solo llamadas al momento a bd.

Comment: Otra pregunta. Veo como tag `asp`? Te refieres a asp clásico o a asp.net?

Comment: Según los Tags asp.net es un framework de ASP, ergo debiese ser asp, pero en verdad la página no tiene ni CSS, si es para publicar datos para ser consumidos por aplicaciones, no es directamente lo que me preguntas, pero bastará con decir que es un web Forms sin página maestra.

Comment: En realidad asp y asp.net son dos tecnologías totalmente diferentes, pero si me hablas de Webforms, entonces hablamos de asp.net. La extensión de las paginas asp clasico es `.asp`, las de asp.net son `.aspx`. Fíjate en la explicación del tag `asp`.

Comment: Yo no tengo ni idea de IIS, pero me he encontrado esto, lo mismo da pistas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306380/can-you-prevent-your-asp-net-application-from-shutting-down

Comment: @Pablo Lozano si pones eso como respuesta, yo te la acepto como la correcta.

Saludos

Comment: Como hacer esto depende de que version de Windows Server y IIS estés usando. Podrías adicionar esta información ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si tienes acceso a la configuración del servidor, la mejor solución es evitar que la aplicación se "apague" por falta de uso: Desactiva la opción **Idle timeout** en las propiedades de la "Application Pool". Puedes ver todos los detalles [aquí](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/desarrolloweb/2012/05/08/asp-net-la-primera-llamada-a-la-aplicacin-tarda-tanto-que-aparecen-timeouts/) y la versión en inglés de esta pregunta [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306380/can-you-prevent-your-asp-net-application-from-shutting-down)

[image: IIS Performance]